# Importing XML into Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.6, importexport, magento-2.0

I have a store in Magento 1.6 on a shared server. Now, I want to **export all of the products and categories from this server, and import them into a new Magento 2.**

The problem is, that the Magento 1.6 exports as XML, while the Magento 2 imports as CSV.

How can I import the XML to Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

This migration tool worked great for me.

https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/

Comment: Your solution requires access to the Magento 1.X database. Since it's a shared host, I don't have this access. I can only access the Admin Dashboard.

Comment: you only need ftp to upload the files, and the database login info, which can be gotten from the Magento 1.6 local.xml. you don't need direct database access.

Comment: I don't have ftp access nor access to the local.xml on the Magento 1.X. That's a managed Magento.

Answer (score 0):

#### Look for a tool to convert xml to cvs.

Ex:

- http://www.convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm
- http://xmlgrid.net/xml2text.html

You can login into Magento 2 admin and go to import. There you will be able to get a sample csv of the accepted format.

If you cvs does not match its accepted format. You need to used find and replace and other text manipulation tools to make it match.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can by default export products in CSV format on Magento 1.x, use dataflow profile Export All Products on System -> Import / Export -> Dataflow profiles
Default profiles also can be customised per your requirements with various settings and flexible XML config of each profile.

Our commercial paid extension allow import of XML with flexible mapping - https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html